# How to retain the same form in the UI when a submit button is clicked in form_tag in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `form_tag` in my Rails app. When I click on the submit button, the form is re-rendered. I would like to stop the re-rendering and I would like to retain the original form with all the input fields even when the submit button is clicked.

How can I achieve this? Pls help!

```
<%= form_tag generate_report_path(:header => true) do |f| % >
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div style="padding-right:10px">

    <%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select(
      [["Select Report Type", 0],
      ["Report1", 1],
      ["Report2", 2],
      ["Report3", 3]]), id: "report_selection") %>


      <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>
```

I have a `select_tag` in my form as shown above which the user uses to select the report which he would like to generate (report1 or 2 or 3)

Based on the selection above, a different set of input controls would be displayed right below the `select_tag dropdown` shown above.

When the user selects the values he likes on the input controls and then clicks on the submit button (labelled as "generate report"), this is what happens:

- all the input controls that were displayed right below the `select_tag dropdown` disappear leaving behind only the `select_tag dropdown` with the default selection (so that the user can once again select the report which he would like to generate)

How can I disable the above step and retain all the input controls (which were displayed below the `select_tag dropdown`) even after the user clicks the submit button?

Pls help!

Comment: try return from the generate_report action without redirect. and add `data: { disable_with: false }` to the submit button this will prevent rendering the page again and will retain the page as it is,and you can click on the submit button as much times.

Comment: This approach works for me - 1) the form does not change and 2) the excel report also downloads successfully unlike the approach suggested by @Adam . However, there is one minor issue here though -> after I click on the submit button, the button got replaced with a very small rectangle resembling a negative symbol ('-').

Comment: However, this worked for me like a charm without any issue at all - `<%= button_tag "Generate Report", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary'%>` (earlier I was using an HTML button instead of `button_tag` -> `<button type="submit" class= "btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Generate Report</button>`).

It appears the solution is to just replace HTML button with `button_tag` and nothing else needs to be done!

Comment: You could post this as an answer if you'd like and I'll mark it as my answer. Thanks for your inputs - otherwise I would not have tried `button_tag` at all!!

Comment: happy to here it works... i will post as answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace HTML button with `button_tag` -> `<%= button_tag "Generate Report", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary'%>` and this would fix the page refresh issue.

Comment: I have one more related question. I use a checkbox right next to the submit button. When the checkbox is clicked:

1) The report download should not happen and instead it should be rendered in an `ActiveJob` (The rendering inside `ActiveJob` happens fine and that is not an issue). 
2) I also to display an alert to the user saying "your report would be emailed to you in a few minutes"

contd ...

Comment: check in action whether the checkbox is clicked or not by `if format_reqd == "1" reload else return`

Comment: Now, 

1) If I use an HTML checkbox, a) the page refreshes but b) the alert gets displayed successfully
`<input type="checkbox" name="format_reqd" id="format_reqd" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" %>
<%= label_tag 'Check for Numeric format' %> `
2) If I use a `check_box_tag`, a) the page does not refresh but b) the alert does not get displayed either
`<%= label_tag do %>
 <%= check_box_tag "format_reqd", "format_reqd", false %>
 Check for Numeric format
<% end %>`

contd ...

Comment: What should I do so that when the checkbox is clicked before clicking the submit button, a) the page should NOT refresh and also b) an alert SHOULD get displayed?

Comment: if you are using a check_box_tag check the `name` of the checkbox after loading the page by inspecting it. the check the in action `if name_of_checkbox == "1" redirect else return`

Comment: In the controller, I do this check -> `if(params[:format_reqd]=="on")` 

This used to work perfectly for HTML label. Should this be changed if I use `check_box_tag`?

Comment: sorry... You have to use params[:format_reqd] . if this work then no need to use check_box_tag

Comment: I have posted a related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736155/in-rails-is-it-possible-to-display-an-alert-without-calling-redirect-to-or-rend

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Form_tag support the remote option.

See

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

try

```
<%= form_tag(generate_report_path(:header => true), remote: true) do |f| % >
```

It changes the request into a xml request, so the browser won't refresh page after getting response.

You can read rails guides for more details.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: this works for me - there's just one issue though. I am rendering an excel report when the submit button is clicked; and the excel report gets downloaded in the browser automatically after it is generated. After I made `remote: true`, the excel templates are being rendered fine; however the download of the report does not happen anymore! Any ideas why this issue and how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know. But I think you have done it. Good job.

Comment: I wonder what's the difference between the HTML code generated by `button_tag` and the normal HTML button which I has used earlier? What would cause page refresh to not happen exactly? It's still not clear!